# The image I got from the internet does not show in the unity image object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The image I got from the internet does not show in the unity image object,
I am using Unity 2019,
I searched a lot, I entered almost every form,
Some resources seemed to work, but,
This time, the image in the image object was displayed with a big red question mark,
Can you please help me how I can display the image I got from the internet in my image object?

Comment: Please read how to ask. Because this as it stands has nothing to work from.

Comment: Welcome to stack pease read [ask]. edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having.

Comment: Are you downloading the image at runtime?

Comment: @JDormer yes . But i see a red question mark

Comment: my purpose is not to download .to show

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Also `unity-container` is not in any way related to the GameEngine Unity3d